# Start service not active in netbeans

Tags: java, database, netbeans, javadb

I'm new to Java and net beans. I started to create database but when I right click `Java DB` in service. I found `create database` and `start service`  not active . Is there anything should I do ? and Should I start service before create database ?

Comment: You probably don't have that package installed. Try downloading NetBeans with full Java EE stack

Comment: excuse me , is Java EE different from jdk1.6