# Couldn't install derby in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, derby

I'm new to java . I'm using eclipse. I want to create database project using derby . I installed two files for derby called `derby_ui_doc_plugin_1.1.3.zip` and `derby_core_plugin_10.8.2.zip` and extracted them in plug ins of eclipse but when I opened the eclipse I couldn't find `data management or data source` or anything that told me that derby is installed . Thanks in advance

i'm working on `Kepler Service Release 2`  if version is old . how can i update it ?

Comment: Those plugins are extremely old and are no longer supported by Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for replying , how can i fix it  > please

Comment: There is no fix. Derby no longer provide an UI for Eclipse. You can still use the Derby jars to access databases but there is no UI.

Comment: so you mean to import dreby.jar as external jar file only ?

Comment: To use the derby jars in a plugin you include them in a plugin. External jars are very difficult to use in a plugin.

Comment: can you help on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829129/start-service-not-active-in-netbeans?noredirect=1#comment72773750_42829129 ?

Comment: I don't use netbeans

Comment: thanks for your replying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These plugins are very old and are not supported by current versions of Eclipse.

Derby no longer provide a UI or plugins for Eclipse. You can still use the Derby jars in plugins but without the UI.

To use the Derby jars in an Eclipse plugin include them in the plugin folder and add the jars to the plugin classpath. You do this by opening the MANIFEST.MF editor and add the jars to the 'Classpath' list on the 'Runtime' tab.

Comment: You just double click on the plugin MANIFEST.MF

Comment: Note that this is only if you want to use Derby in an Eclipse plugin. For a plain Java program you use external jars.